# C# db query where conditions are met, orderby date and then get the first result

Tags: c#, linq

While evaluating some queries we found some possible optimization. The ideia is shown below but I currently don't know how to solve this.

Current query:

```
public static List<Object> SampleQuerySales(int store_id)
{
    var query = (from clients in db.table1.Where(p => p.store_id == store_id)
                from sales in db.table2.Where(q => q.customer_id == clients.customer_id))
                select new Object {
                ...
                }).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

This returns all sales made, but its required only the latest sale (`OperationDate`) from a datetime reference. As obvious this became a bottleneck.

My ideia was to make it similar to query below, which is incorrect (doesn't compile). How can I achieve this dataset?

```
    var query = (from clients in db.table1.Where(p => p.store_id == store_id)
                from sales in db.table2.Where(q => q.customer_id == clients.customer_id
                && q.OperationDate <= dateReference)
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.OperationDate).FirstOrDefault() //error
                select new Object {
                ...
                }).Tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want one value from table2, use `let` instead of `from`:

```
    var query = (from client in db.table1.Where(p => p.store_id == store_id)
                let mostRecentSaleAfterDateReference = db.table2
                  .Where(q => q.customer_id == client.customer_id
                              && q.OperationDate <= dateReference)
                  .OrderByDescending(s => s.OperationDate)
                  .FirstOrDefault() 
                select new Object {
                ...
                }).Tolist();
```

Comment: Thank you. Does it (change from ```from``` to ```let```) make a performance decrease? I've noticed a worse scenario here with my numbers, but I'm not sure if it's some other think I've change.